# Get background location updates periodically stops

Tags: android

I'm building a simple android application which basically gets the device's location periodically in the background every minute using Fused Location Services.

I've implemented the application based on this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/#0

So far the application is working fine getting the location as I need it (every minute) while I use the device every now and then. I tried another testing scenario where I left the device 
overnight to gather location updates and the day after I looked at the locations history that I'm saving for every location update. I noticed that the location updates were as follows:

- first few hours location updates were every minute (as expected)
- then it started getting location every approx 10 minutes for another few minutes
- then it stopped for several hours without getting any location updates

After this I grabbed the device and traveled from one place to another and without even turning on the screen of the device it started getting the location updates every minute while I traveled. (This might have happened coincidentally)

NOTE: The above testing scenarios were done on devices which are pre-oreo.

QUESTIONS:

1. Could it be that the device starts getting the location updates every minute when it detects automatically that it started moving from one place to another and then it stops getting 
   the location updates as soon as it detects that the device is at the same position for some hours?
2. Is there a recommended way to keep getting location updates always every minute and even when the device is at the same location and not being used?

We need to keep getting location updates as the updates are being used as a heartbeat of the application.

Comment: The first transition was definitely Doze.  Doze is pre-Oreo, and it basically prevents any app from waking up more than a certain frequency when the screen is off and the phone is sleeping.  This frequency is about once every 10-15 minutes.  The second could be a deeper level of Doze.  If you were to accidentally have hit the screen on button, it would explain the updates starting again.  You can whitelist your app from Doze, but it needs to be done manually by each user-  no way to do it programatically. See https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Answer (score 0):

you also can use this solution :

check if location is not received  for 2 min stop and then start location update.